# Using neocities and can't link the CSS to HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>an infinite endeavor</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
```

The CSS is a separate file, and I've been searching for hours for a solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GdHj.png

Comment: is your css file in the same directory as your html file?

Comment: How is your project architecture? you have view, css folders?

Comment: What does happen if you do "./style.css" ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your CSS file in a CSS folder? If so do not forget to add css/ to entering your CSS folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

or try like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

Comment: I added a photo of how it's set up if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is troubleshooting, so I will give you three viable answers.

1. Maybe your css file is not in the same directory as your HTML file.
2. If you are loading this locally, remember to write the ENTIRE file location ex: C://User/desktop/styles.css
3. If none work, think about just copypasting the entire css code and putting it inside a  tag.

Comment: @Kayla I saw your image, just make it a local file on your PC or computer. It will be much easier to use rather than relying on a third party's option.